# Combining array values in multilevel array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like so:

```
array(
    'a'=>array(
        'a'=>3,
        'f'=>5,
        'sdf'=>0),
    't'=>array(
        'a'=>1,
        'f'=>2,
        'sdf'=>5),
    'pps'=>array(
        'a'=>1,
        'f'=>2,
        'sdf'=>3)
);
```

Notice how the sub-arrays are the same for each top-level array.  If I wanted to, what's the easiest way to combine the sub-arrays so that I'm left with a one-dimensional array like:

```
array(
    'a'=>5,
    'f'=>9,
    'sdf'=>8
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  foreach ($value as $k => $a) {
    if ( ! isset($result[$k])) $result[$k] = 0;
    $result[$k] += $a;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was using .= instead of += - saved me a headache!!

Answer (score 0):

What about two nested foreach and actually creating a new array ?

```
$input = array(
    'a'=>array(
        'a'=>3,
        'f'=>5,
        'sdf'=>0),
    't'=>array(
        'a'=>1,
        'f'=>2,
        'sdf'=>5),
    'pps'=>array(
        'a'=>1,
        'f'=>2,
        'sdf'=>3)
);

$output = array();
foreach ($input as $v) {
    foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
        if (!isset ($output[$k2])
            $output[$k2] = 0;
        $output[$k2] += $v2;
    }
}

/* Now $output = array(
       'a'=>5,
       'f'=>9,
       'sdf'=>8
   ); */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function($val, $key) {
  global $result;
  $result[$key] += $val;
});
```